# Lindemann theorem for Artin-Hasse exponential

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-approximation, p-adic-analysis, transcendental-number-theory

Though the Lindemann--Weierstrass theorem is not known in the $p$-adic settings, its "Lindemann" part -- the transcendence of $\exp(a)$ for algebraic $a$ with $0<|a|_p<p^{-1/(p-1)}$ -- was shown by K. Mahler in 1932. Is there anything known (unconditionally!) about the transcendence of the values of the Artin--Hasse exponential
$$
E_p(x)=\exp\biggl(x+\frac{x^p}p+\frac{x^{p^2}}{p^2}+\dots+\frac{x^{p^n}}{p^n}+\dots\biggr)\in\mathbb Z_p[[x]]
$$
at algebraic $a$ with $0<|a|_p<1$?

Comment: Is $E_p$ known to be a transcendental function? I seem to recall that $E_p \pmod p$ is not known to be a transcendental function.

Comment: Felipe, if $E_p(x)$ is algebraic then $E_p(x^p)$ is algebraic and so is $E_p(x^p)/E_p(x)^p=\exp(-px)$, a contradiction. Thakur asks (page 15 in https://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/dthakur2/autbanffFinal.pdf) whether the mod $p$ reduction of $E_p(x)$ is transcendental over $\mathbb F_p(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

The following will probably shed neither light nor heat on your question, but perhaps it does offer another way of looking at it:

I look at the Artin-Hasse series not as any kind of exponential but as the  strict isomorphism between two height-one formal groups, namely the formal group of multiplication $\hat{\mathbf G}_{\mathrm m}(x,y)=x+y+xy$ and its $p$-typicalization $\mathcal F_p$, whose logarithm is exactly the series displayed in your question, namely $\mathcal L_p(x)=\sum_0^\infty p^{-n}x^{p^n}$.

The Artin-Hasse series $E_p:\mathcal F_p\to\hat{\mathbf G}_{\mathrm m}$ is a strict isomorphism, and you’re asking whether it takes suitably small algebraic (over $\Bbb Q$) elements of $\Bbb Z_p$ to algebraic elements (of $\Bbb Z_p$).

Whether it makes sense to ask the same question of the (substitional) inverse of $E_p$ I’ll leave to others to judge; but I’ll go ahead and ask it. In particular, one might ask, just in characteristic $2$, whether the $2$-torsion element of $\hat{\mathbf G}_{\mathrm m}$, namely $-2$, has an algebraic or transcendental image under $E_2^{-1}$. This image, of course, is the unique $2$-torsion element of $\mathcal F_2$, and this is the unique $\Bbb Z_2$-rational root of $\mathcal L_2(x)$. I see no reason why this number should be algebraic; a proof either way would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the Dwork exponential $E(x)=\exp(\pi(x-x^p))$ with $\pi=\sqrt[p-1]{-p}$. It is well known that $E(1)=\gamma_p$ a $p$-th root of $1$ and hence not transcendant.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your answer: this is more a $p$-adic analogue of $\exp(\pi ia)$ being a root of unity for rational $a$... My question is about the other $p$-adic exponential, which has a worse domain of convergence but mimics $\exp(x)$ rather than $\exp(\pi ix)$.